# Not dismiss dialog when using multiple choice AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm using `setAdapter()` on `AlertDialog.Builder` to supply my own custom `ListAdapter` for my list. But after my `DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` is called the dialog is automatically dismissed.

Below there is the Android source code in `AlertController.createListView(...)` that causes my dialog to dismiss:

```
if (mOnClickListener != null) {
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
      mOnClickListener.onClick(dialog.mDialogInterface, position);
      if (!mIsSingleChoice) {
        dialog.mDialogInterface.dismiss();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Currently I'm using `AlertDialog.Builder.setSingleChoiceItems(..)` instead of `setAdapter(..)`. Is there any better way to use a custom `ListAdapter` and allow multiple choice in the dialog? I find it misleading to use `setSingleChoiceItems` for a multiple choice list.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    m_adapter = new MyAdapter();
    builder.setAdapter(m_adapter, new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
    });

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    // override default behavior of dismissing dialog on clicking list item
    final ListView listView = alertDialog.getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }
    });

    return alertDialog;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dismiss AlertDailog in either way of using `Handler` class. See following code,

```
if (mOnClickListener != null) 
{
     listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
     { 
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) 
         {
            mOnClickListener.onClick(dialog.mDialogInterface, position);
           if (!mIsSingleChoice) 
           {
               //dialog.mDialogInterface.dismiss();
              // call handler class as follows, 
                 handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
           }
        }
   });
}


private Handler handler = new Handler()
{
      @Override
      public void handleMessage ( Message message )
      {
          dialog.mDialogInterface.dismiss();
      }
};
```